# Updating a count in a template_file is not affecting the output

Tags: terraform

We have a system in place that uses a number of counted resources.  Up until now, they have been hardcoded to 2.  I've just introduced a new variable, `pairs`, with a default of 1 so we can start to increase this.  If it stays on that default of 1, the resulting `plan` shows no changes.  Here are the two items in play amongst many others:

```
data "template_file" "bootstrapuserdata" {
    count   = "${var.pairs * 2}"
    template = "${file("${path.module}/startup.ps1")}"
    vars {
        domain = "${var.domain}"
        region = "${var.region}"
        publicIp = "${element(var.public_ips, count.index)}"
        stack = "${var.stack}"
    }
}


resource "aws_launch_configuration" "lc" {
    count = "${var.pairs * 2}"
    name_prefix = "lc-${element(var.private_subnet_ids, count.index)}-"
    image_id = "${var.ami_id}"
    instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
    iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.webserver_instance_profile.id}"
    key_name = "${var.key_name}"
    security_groups = ["${var.sg_id}", "${var.sg2_id}"]
    user_data = "${data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.*.rendered[count.index]}"
    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }
}
```

If I change the value of `pairs` to 2 (resulting in a count of 4 for both items), I get the following error from the `plan`:

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:


* module.servers.aws_launch_configuration.lc: 2 error(s) occurred:

* module.servers.aws_launch_configuration.lc[3]: index 3 out of range for list data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.*.rendered (max 2) in:

${data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.*.rendered[count.index]}
* module.servers.aws_launch_configuration.lc[2]: index 2 out of range for list data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.*.rendered (max 2) in:

${data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.*.rendered[count.index]}
```

It's like it's not re-rendered the `template_file` with the updated count.  If I deliberately break the `template_file`, that sort of confirms it:

```
data "template_file" "bootstrapuserdata" {
    count   = "${var.pairs * 2}"
    template = "${file("${path.module}/startup.ps1")}"
    vars {
        #domain = "${var.domain}"
        region = "${var.region}"
        publicIp = "${element(var.public_ips, count.index)}"
        stack = "${var.stack}"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.servers.data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata: 2 error(s) occurred:

* module.servers.data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata[1]: data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.1: failed to render : 28:66: unknown variable accessed: domain
* module.servers.data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata[0]: data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.0: failed to render : 28:66: unknown variable accessed: domain
```

However, if I *really* break the `template_file`:

```
data "template_file" "bootstrapuserdata" {
    count   = "${var.pairs * 2}"
    template = "${file("${path.module}/startup.ps1")}"
    /*vars {
        domain = "${var.domain}"
        region = "${var.region}"
        publicIp = "${element(var.public_ips, count.index)}"
        stack = "${var.stack}"
    }*/
}
```

It now knows about all 4:

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.servers.data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata: 4 error(s) occurred:

* module.servers.data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata[3]: data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.3: failed to render : 15:106: unknown variable accessed: domain
* module.servers.data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata[1]: data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.1: failed to render : 15:106: unknown variable accessed: domain
* module.servers.data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata[2]: data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.2: failed to render : 15:106: unknown variable accessed: domain
* module.servers.data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata[0]: data.template_file.bootstrapuserdata.0: failed to render : 15:106: unknown variable accessed: domain
```

What's going on?  Have I stumbled across a Terraform bug?

I started the day on Terraform 0.10.6, but upgraded to 0.11.10 after seeing this issue - there's no difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done further looking, and [finding this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18724), I tried experimenting a little:

If I switch to use `resource "template_file"` instead of `data "template_file"` *and also change the name of my template*, it fixes my issue.  Keeping it on `data` and changing the name doesn't work, and switching to `resource` without changing the name also doesn't work.

All in all, this does look to be an issue within Terraform itself at some level, whether it's the one I linked to above or not, I'm not sure yet.

---

*Follow up, almost a year later*:

The issue I linked to above has been closed [in favour of this one](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17034), which describes my problem perfectly.  So yes, this is a long standing issue in the way Terraform calculates these contents, and I'll be stuck on `resource` rather than `data` for a while yet.